# Could you please explain the sentences for me?

Tags: meaning

> 1. She will never go back to her husband, she has done with him for good.

What does this sentence mean?  What does 'do with someone' means?

> 2. He is a strange fellow, I just can't make him out.

What does the second part mean?

Comment: You should ask the second question separately.

Comment: In the first sentence, it should probably be "her husband".

Comment: This question should have more [details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), starting with **where you found these quotes**. Context can make a big difference! Please edit it accordingly. (Also, are you sure the first reads, "She _has_ done with him"? I would think it would be, "She _is_ done with him.")

Comment: The construction "she has done with him for good" is found in _Mr Magsdale's Courtship_ by Edward Cuming, as published in four parts in 1888 in _Chamber's Journal of Popular Literature_.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. [done with](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-done-with)
>      to end relations with

I assume you meant "She will never go back to **her** husband, she **is** done with him for good". She has ended her relation/relationship with him forever.

> 2. [make out](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20out)
>      :  to form an opinion or idea about :  conclude

So the speaker cannot make any conclusions or form opinions about the strange fellow. As J.R. points out, we might simply say that the speaker cannot understand the strange fellow. This would include understanding his

1. feelings
2. thoughts
3. personality

or other aspects regarding this person.

Comment: A good paraphrase for #2 would be, "I can't understand him."

Comment: I agree, but I wasn't sure if OP would understand that, so I did not include it.

Comment: For a leaner, I think "understand" would be easier to figure out than "conclude."

Comment: That's interesting. I think it has potential to be misunderstood. I was thinking that a learner might think that it would mean understand the fellow's words, or something like that.

Comment: That's a good point. It's (usually) more like the person's mannerisms and quirks that are hard to understand. In any event, I thought it was worth trying to clarify a bit more.

Comment: I also thought it was worth expanding my answer. Thanks for the comment.